# Calculating sum of manhattan distances in a sliding puzzle

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, taxicab-geometry

I would like some feed back on a method which calculates the sum of Manhattan distances for each tile in a sliding puzzle to its goal position in the goal puzzle.

Here is the code:

```
public static int calcManhattanDistance(int[] ps, int[] goal) {
    int rowSz = calculatePuzzleRowSize(ps);
    int manhattanDistanceSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ps.length; j++) {
            if (ps[i] == goal[j])
                manhattanDistanceSum += (Math.abs(i/rowSz - j/rowSz) + Math.abs(i%rowSz - j%rowSz)); 
        }
    }
    return manhattanDistanceSum;
}
```

Please tell me if you think something should be changed or what I can do to increase efficiency.

Here is the `calculatePuzzleRowSize(ps)` method:

```
public static int calculatePuzzleRowSize(int[] ps) {
    int sz = ps.length;
    int rowSz = (int) Math.sqrt(sz);
    return rowSz;
}
```

Here is the newly implemented `calculateManhattanDistanceSum`

```
public static int calculateManhattanDistanceSum(int[] ps, int[] goal) {
    int rowSize = (int) Math.sqrt(ps.length);
    int manhattanDistanceSum = 0;
    Map<Integer, Integer> psMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i : ps)
        psMap.put(ps[i], i);
    for (int j : goal)
        manhattanDistanceSum += Math.abs(psMap.get(j)/rowSize - j/rowSize) + Math.abs(psMap.get(j)%rowSize - j%rowSize); 
    return manhattanDistanceSum;
}
```

Comment: Can you add what the `calculatePuzzleRowSize` method is? Even if it's trivial, it'd be helpful to have the full program here.

Comment: @lealand It's added :)

Comment: Your algorithm complexity is quadratic in the number of pieces. You can reduce it to linearitmic by first creating a dictionary with the reverse mapping of ps, and then use it while iterating on the elements of goal.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Hello, I implemented your idea. However, the time increased. I think this might be due to extra time initializing a map and adding things in there. Also, since it is almost impossible to solve puzzles past 4x4, at least with my implementation, I feel like quadratic time is negligible since the most I can ever do is 16^2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you hold the right order of the puzzle pieces in the goal-array, wouldn't it be natural that the right order itsself is 0 to #pieces - 1?

If that's the case, you could calculate the manhatten distance by just iterating over ps[]:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ps.length; i++)
    if( ps[i] == i ) continue;
else
    manhattanDistanceSum += (Math.abs(ps[i]/rowSz - i/rowSz) + Math.abs(ps[i]%rowSz - i%rowSz));
```

Comment: Hi, the goal state of the puzzle is not necessarily from 0 to 9. The user inputs a goal state.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor observations on the style:

- You have two methods: `calculatePuzzleRowSize` and `calcManhattanDistance`. You should be consistent in the naming and either choose `calc` or `calculate`, though I think that `get` would be more conventional, i.e. `getPuzzleRowSize` and `getManhattenDistance`.
- `calculatePuzzleRowSize` is unnecessary. Just go `int rowSz = (int) Math.sqrt(ps.length)`
- Use expressive variable names. What does `ps` mean? Instead of `rowSz`, just call it `rowSize`. The characters are free and you avoid the cognitive hiccup when reading your code.
- Spaces are your friend. Many IDEs can automatically format code in a consistent format:

  ```
  manhattanDistanceSum += Math.abs(i / rowSz - j / rowSz) + Math.abs(i % rowSz - j % rowSz);
  ```

I do wonder why you're using a 1D array for what is intrinsically at 2D problem.

Comment: I would disagree with using `get` for the name. It's a calculation, so `calculate` would be better (it implies that the function takes time, while `get` implies that it returns a stored value). But I do agree that it should be consistent.

Comment: @tim That's fair enough. I really only want to stress consistency.